# heroku not updating after I git push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

`git push heroku` everything is fine, then `heroku open` - but it is only the rails landing page that shows. When I try `rails s` my home page is loaded perfectly. I deleted the public/index.html and commited/pushed changes to github. What could be causing this?

routes.rb:

```
Oxenblog::Application.routes.draw do
root :to => 'static_pages#about'

match '/about',    to: 'static_pages#about'
match '/contact',  to: 'static_pages#contact'
match '/projects', to: 'static_pages#projects'
```

I think it is a problem with what I am doing with heroku, because it looks fine in localhost...

it is something with the git branches. I have added commited and pushed to both github and heroku , and `Everything is up to date` . however `heroku open` is still showing the rails landing page, very frustrating. I am on the master branch, this is a newish project so I have yet to make any new branches.

Comment: Do you use multiple branches or are you using only `master` branch?

Comment: `On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit. `  then I did `git push origin master` - still same rails landing page

Comment: did you do `git push heroku master`?

Comment: when i enter that command, i receive `Everything up-to-date` - yet still shows the rails page, very confusing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting the default Rails homepage isn't enough, you have to instruct git to remove all deleted files. This is the command I use:

```
git add .
git commit -am "save all changed files & remove deleted ones"
git push heroku master
```

Other commands that should work:

```
git add . -A
git commit -m "..."

git add -u
git commit -m "..."
```

Note that if you delete files before doing any commits then git can't add them.

Comment: Are you saying OP had deleted filed but didn't do `git rm --cached`? I'm having the same problem; the index.html file has been deleted and pushed, and I confirmed via `heroku run ls public` that it doesn't exist on heroku, yet I still